# Virtual Emulator Freeze in android studio on windows 10

Tags: flutter, dart, android-emulator, virtual, freeze

I am doing my first project on android studio but Virtual emulator is freezing every time I run, it start to get black screen and showing 'no device selected' even I have open virtual emulator and its up working fine but when I run code virtual emulator wont respond.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question needs to be more detailed about your environment and versions you use for others to be able to help you. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try running a cold boot for your android emulator. You can do this by navigating to the emulator files on your OS. If you are using Windows OS, this terminal command would look something like this:

```
cd C:\Users\your-account\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator>
```

Once you have navigated to the emulator directory, you can force a cold boot by running the following command:

```
.\emulator.exe -avd Your_Device_Name -no-snapshot-load
```

It is not clear from your question what code editor you are using, but this is effective in Visual Studio Code, especially if you have installed the Android iOS Emulator extension.